# How to set a fixed refresh rate in Remote Desktop Connection (full-screen)?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, refresh-rate

I have a monitor ([LG UltraGear 34GP36A](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34gp63a-b-gaming-monitor) connected in the display port of a Radeon RX 6600 GPU) running at 160Hz in Windows 11, when I connect to a remote machine through RDP in windowed mode everything works well, but going full-screen causes the screen to start "blinking" and have some issues related to the variation of the refresh rate (I could check on the monitor's menu, that when I'm in fullscreen mode, the refresh rate varies from 55 to 100Hz).

Setting the Windows 11 refresh rate configuration to 60Hz resolves the problem, but I don't want to change this configuration every single time I'm going to connect RDP.

And there's no problem with any cable or hardware, as I'm able to play some games in fullscreen @ 160Hz without any problem.

How can I set the refresh rate of the RPD full-screen connection, without changing the Windows refresh rate configuration?

Comment: So what exactly isn’t working?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but to make changing resolution just a keypress or icon click, make two batch scripts using qres.exe, https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/qres,1.html .

Comment: @Ramhound going full-screen causes the screen to start "blinking" and have some issues related to the variation of the refresh rate. I would like to fix this, or set a fixed refresh for RDP connections, without changing the Windows refresh rate configuration every time

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "FreeSync Premium" configuration of the monitor from "Extended" to "Basic" fixed the problem.